# call OSGI Service IPreferenceStore using JavaScript in Sabre RedApp

Tags: sabre

I have created Sabre Red App web service application using RedApp_2.10 Developer Toolkit.
The application is similar to com.sabre.redapp.example.cf.webapp.services example from the toolkit. The application contains few settings that are stored in org.eclipse.jface.preference.IPreferenceStore Java container, as it shown in example com.sabre.redapp.example.editor.basic. As a result, I can see and edit the settings in Tools->Options->Red Apps Settings->myApp page of RedApp.

How can I access to the settings from my web page using JavaScript? Guess I need to use callOSGIService function. But it returns only error:
"Service org.eclipse.jface.preference.IPreferenceStore cannot be called from JS".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment the Red App SDK does not provide a direct interface to access IPreferenceStore directly through JavaScript.

An option to achieve this is accessing the IPreferenceStore through a native Java Class, and have it communicate with the Browser component through custom Javascript function that would expose this. Red App SDK provides examples related to advanced browser communication from Java Script.

Answer (score 1):

I'd agree with Julian.

Just create your own browser extending the default one
and extend it declaring a JavaScript callback function:

```
public class MbBrowserEditor extends DefaultBrowserEditor {

    ...

    public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
        super.createPartControl(parent);
        this.registerJavaScriptCallback(new MbJavascriptCallback(this), "callSWS");
    }

    ...
}
```

the registererd JavaScriptCallback could be like this:

```
public class MbJavascriptCallback extends JavaScriptCallback {

    MbBrowserEditor browserView = null;

    // javascript callback function name
    String sbMergeBack = "callBackFromPnrMb";
    // parameters for the javascript callback function
    String sSuccess = "true";
    String sMessage = "PNR Merge Back executed successfully";
    String sErrorDetail = "No error";
    ...

    /**
     * this function will be called by JS to execute a SWS workflow
     * it expects the following parameters :
     * items        :   an array of strings
     * transactions :   an array of strings
     * cbMergeBack  :   a string
     */
    @Override
    public void function(Object[] arguments) {
        // do your stuff
        callBackWebApp();
    }


    private void callBackWebApp() {
        ...

        // callback javascript (with 3 params - set your own)
        final String cbFunction = sbMergeBack+"(\"" + sSuccess + "\", \"" + sMessage + "\", \"" + sErrorDetail + "\");";

        Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ...
                try {
                    browserView.executeJavaScript(cbFunction);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ...
                }
            }
        });
    }
    ...
}
```

that worked fine [here](http://servicemix.eu/catalog)